# Accessing sprite nodes added in loop to call class inherited method?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a number of SKSpriteNodes, adding them to the scene in a for loop.

```
func addBlocks(number : Int) {
    for _ in 1...number {
        let block = Obstacle()
        addChild(block)
    }

}
```

Since they're created in this loop, I can't call `block.myMethod()`. I can do of course call`childNodeWithName("block")` to perform things it inherits by being a node, like `.removeFromParent()`.
What should I do if I want to call the method implemented in the Obstacle class (subclass of SKSpriteNode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Obstacle subclass of SKSpriteNode

Let's say you have `Obstacle` defined as follow.

```
class Obstacle: SKSpriteNode {
    func explode() { }
}
```

### Obstacles with names

If you add an `Obstacle` to the scene you can add a name to the node like

```
func addBlocks(number : Int) {
    for i in 1...number {
        let block = Obstacle()
        block.name = "block_\(i)" // <-- like here
        addChild(block)
    }
}
```

### Retrieving an SKNode by name and casting it to Obstacle

Next when you invoke `self.childNodeWithName(...)` you get something like this `SKNode?`.

It means you can receive nil or something that is an `SKNode`. If you believed (like in this case) that the returned object is something more specific of an SKNode (like Obstacle) the you can try to cast it to your custom class type.

```
func explodeObstacle(i: Int) {
    guard let obstacle = self.childNodeWithName("block_\(i)") as? Obstacle else {
        debugPrint("Could not find an Obstacle with name block_\(i)")
        return
    }
    obstacle.explode()
}
```

In the code below, if the cast does fail (which mean the returned value is not an `Obstacle`, then an error message is printed on the console).
Otherwise if the value is successfully casted do `Obstacle`, you can invoke any method you added to `Obstacle`.